# Navigation view fragments and child backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack

I've handled fragments before but that was with a view pager and tablayout and I was able to keep the fragments state by building an array and returning a frag from that array.

but now using fragment manager, I have access to add and replace, but both create new instances of my fragments without saving what has occured (i.e. typing on editText).

How can I keep or reuse the fragments I've created when navigating from the menu (keep in mind some of these fragments will have a child backstack, the back button should only take you out of deep fragments not my main ones)

current code

```
 private void initNavigation(){
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    /* Initialize fragments for navigation drawer */
    fragments = new Fragment[]{
            new ProfileFragment(),
            new StatsFragment()};

    /* Set selection of navigation item */
    nav_view = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    item.setChecked(true);

                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.nav_routine:
                            if(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("TAG0") != null){
                                Log.i("fm", "reloading profile frag");
                                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main,
                                        fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("TAG0"), "TAG0");
                            } else{
                                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, fragments[0], "TAG0").commit();
                            }
                            break;
                       default:
                           if(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("TAG1") != null){
                               Log.i("fm", "reloading stats frag");
                               fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main,
                                       fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("TAG1"), "TAG1");
                           } else{
                               fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, fragments[1], "TAG1").commit();
                           }
                           break;
                   }

                   drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                   return true;
               }
           }
    );
}
```

**Edit solved:**

I found out that in order for a view to be saved it must have an ID (makes sense). Also I wasn't using `.commit()` with some of my `.replace` in my prior code

```
nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
             new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    item.setChecked(true);

                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.nav_routine:
                                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, fragments[0], "TAG0").commit();
                            break;
                       default:
                               fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, fragments[1], "TAG1").commit();
                           break;
                   }

                   drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                   return true;
               }
           }
    );
```

Comment: use onSaveInstanceState for save/reuse your edittext data..

Answer (score 0):

Im not clear with your question .But this is how keeping backState of fragments.

```
Fragment mfragment=new Fragmentname();           

        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, mfragment);
        String backStateName = mfragment.getClass().getName();
        if (position != 0) {
            ft.addToBackStack(backStateName);
        }

        ft.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

As you could save the data of a `Fragment` when leaving from it I think you already know about `SavedInstanceState`. Anyway, while you're transacting one fragment to another from your `Activity` using fragment transaction, you need to add `addToBackStack(null)` before your commit. So the transaction should look like

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, fragments[0], "TAG0").addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

And override the `onBackPressed` function of your `Activity` like this.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    else
        super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: I mean, when navigating between fragments from the menu back and forth, I need to keep whatever I changed. I know for the child fragments (deep fragments) I can use getChildFragmentManager so each main fragment can have their own back stack.